# qemu: Could not set up host forwarding rule

Tags: qemu

[Windows host] when using hostfwd I'm getting this error even on on ports higher than 1024:

`Could not set up host forwarding rule`

It used to work fine, and I haven't updated qemu since. Is it possible that the admin (I'm in a corporate environment) has implemented new restrictions? I can bind a socket using other apps to, e.g. port 8080 with Java.

Comment: No need for admin restrictions; maybe some other program is listening to the same port. Example: `nc -l -p 2222` then `qemu -net user,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22` => `Could not set up host forwarding rule 'tcp::2222-:22'`

Comment: Check with `netstat`, etc

Comment: I did check and there is nothing already bound to port 2222. I also tried other random ports but nothing seems to work. I even tried 8080 since i know for sure I can bind to this port: same.

Comment: Try to limit to a simple reproducible case as in my comment, and check if you can bind to that port with other applications: does `nc -l -p 2222` succeed? Also try tracing qemu with `strace -f` and look for any external commands it runs: in my experience, qemu hides the errors from the help programs it runs under some obtuse or comical error message.

Comment: @pizdelect unfortunately the host is Windows so that limits the choice of diagnostic tools... Is there an equivalent to nc and strace ?

Comment: Not that this question is still current, but can the person who downvoted this question explain why? Downvoting means that "this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". I don't believe any of this applies here.

Comment: I just ran into same issues. Checked with netstat and everything was looking fine. I forgot I have a docker container running which was using port forwarding. So netstat will not show you everything.